# Creating Folders in a Zip Folder in Java

Tags: java, file, zip, directory

My task requires me to save a file directory into a zip folder. My only problem is I need to keep the sub-folders as folders from the main Directory. The file system will look something like

```
C\\Friends
C:\\Friends\\Person1\\Information.txt
C:\\Friends\\Person2\\Information.txt
C:\\Friends\\Person3\\Information.txt
```

.
.
.

Right now I am able to write just the txt files inside of my zip folder, but in my zip folder I need to keep that folder structure. I know the way my code is right now will tell me the file I'm trying to write is closed(No access). My Functions thus far:

```
private String userDirectroy = "" //This is set earlier in the program

public void exportFriends(String pathToFile)
    {
        String source = pathToFile + ".zip";

        try
        {


            String sourceDir = userDirectory;
            String zipFile = source;

            try
            {

                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);


                    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);


                    File fileSource = new File(sourceDir);

                    addDirectory(zout, fileSource);


                    zout.close();

                    System.out.println("Zip file has been created!");
            }       
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("First Function: " + e);

        }
    }

     private static void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, File fileSource) {


         File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();

         System.out.println("Adding directory " + fileSource.getName());

         for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
         {

                 if(files[i].isDirectory())
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                         FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                         zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));

                         int length;

                         while((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                         {
                            zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                         }
                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {
                        System.err.println(e); 
                     }
                         addDirectory(zout, files[i]);
                         continue;
                 }


                 try
                 {
                         System.out.println("Adding file " + files[i].getName());

                         //create byte buffer
                         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                         //create object of FileInputStream
                         FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

                         zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));


                         int length;

                         while((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                         {
                            zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                         }



                          zout.closeEntry();

                          //close the InputStream
                          fin.close();

                 }
                 catch(IOException ioe)
                 {
                         System.out.println("IOException :" + ioe);                             
                 }
         }

 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

For each folder, you need to add a empty `ZipEntry` of the path.

For each file, you need to supply both the path and file name.  This will require you to know the part of the path to strip off, this would be everything after the start directory

**Expanded concept**

So, from your example, if the start directory is `C:\Friends`, then the entry for `C:\Friends\Person1\Information.txt` should look like `Person1\Information.txt`

```
public void exportFriends(String pathToFile) {

    String source = pathToFile + ".zip";
    try {
        String sourceDir = "C:/Friends";
        String zipFile = source;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);

            File fileSource = new File(sourceDir);

            addDirectory(zout, sourceDir, fileSource);

            zout.close();

            System.out.println("Zip file has been created!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getRelativePath(String sourceDir, File file) {
    // Trim off the start of source dir path...
    String path = file.getPath().substring(sourceDir.length());
    if (path.startsWith(File.pathSeparator)) {
        path = path.substring(1);
    }
    return path;
}

private static void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, String sourceDir, File fileSource) throws IOException {
    if (fileSource.isDirectory()) {
        // Add the directory to the zip entry...
        String path = getRelativePath(sourceDir, fileSource);
        if (path.trim().length() > 0) {
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(getRelativePath(sourceDir, fileSource));
            zout.putNextEntry(ze);
            zout.closeEntry();
        }

        File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Adding directory " + fileSource.getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(zout, sourceDir, files[i]);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Adding file " + files[i].getName());

                //create byte buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                //create object of FileInputStream
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(getRelativePath(sourceDir, files[i])));

                int length;

                while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zout.closeEntry();
                //close the InputStream
                fin.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he code runs fine, but I cannot open the file?