# Add a parent folder to a ZIP dynamically while creating it using Java.util.zip.*

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to zip a following direcotry structure :

C:/Test/1
C:/Test/2
C:/Test/3
C:/Test/3/1.txt
C:/Test/3/2.txt
C:/Test/4

---

I have been successfully able to perform the same. The requirement is that I need to segregate the folders dynamically and create parent folders inside the zip. Something like :

Test.zip
TypeA/Test/1
TypeA/Test/2
TypeB/Test/3
TypeB/Test/3/1.txt
TypeB/Test/3/2.txt
TypeB/Test/4

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are the "type" groups determined?  Essentally, you should just create a empty `ZipEntry` whose name is the path you need (ie `TypeA/Test/1`) and then each file would be named `TypeA/Test/1/{filename}`.  The empty "path" entry should only be added once.  For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381281/creating-folders-in-a-zip-folder-in-java/16381391#16381391)

Comment: The code that you have provided in the example is very similar to what I have implemented. What that does is it iterates the folder structure and maintains the physical structure of the folder intact.

The Type is returned from the database as I am populating the file path dynamically based on the flag being returned

Comment: I have, in the past, maintained a simple `List`, which contains a `List` of all the "empty" paths I have created.  So in you case, I guess, generate the file path (ie `Test/1`), you would then request the type from the database based on the file path (ie `TypeA`).  You would then (obviously) create the final path (`TypeA/Test/1`).  You would check the `List` for each directory and create an "empty" `ZipEntry` for it (ie that is, a entry for `TypeA`, `TypeA/Test` and `TypeA/Test/1`).  You would then create the final file name for the file to be added (assuming there is one) and add that file...

Comment: I understand your scenario. Let me give a little more detail regarding the problem. I am creating the zip by fetching folders from 2 different locations in the physical file system. Location1 and Location2.

Now I need to keep them under different parent directories in the zip so that it becomes easier while restoring the folders if required in the future. Does that change the solution at all? :)

Comment: Not really.  Depending on how your code works, you could provide a prefix (for example) for each "parent" folder, which you simply prefix the to the `path/name` of the file you are zipping.  The only requirement is that each level of the folder structure must make up a separate `ZipEntry` as stated above...

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Finally managed to get a hold of my trouble. it was trying to open two zipoutputstreams and that is what was causing the trouble. Fixed it by parsing both folder structures in one method. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :D

Comment: just this one last thing. I need to include a txt file while zipping which has the list of all the files that have been zipped. Can this be done without creating a physical txt file?

Comment: Yes.  Basically you can write the details to a `StringBuilder` or such and convert that resulting `String` to byte array and write it as a new entry to the Zip file...