# Zip File is Invalid?

Tags: java

So the code below is for a Bukkit server. What it does is zip all of the files in the server directory and puts the zip file in a "backups" folder. It works... to some extent.  The files do indeed get copied and zipped, however if I click on the file, there's nothing in it (even though I know there is because it shows the file size next to it) and when I try to unzip it, windows gives me an error stating that the zip file is invalid. Any ideas why? Thanks :)

```
    public class Backup extends Thread{

    private static Backup instance;

    public static Backup getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public static void newRef(){
        instance = new Backup();
    }

    public void backup(final CommandSender sender) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                sender.sendMessage(MessageManager.getChatPrefix() + "Starting backup...");
                Backup.this.startBackup();
                sender.sendMessage(MessageManager.getChatPrefix() + "Done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void backup() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Backup.this.startBackup();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void zipDir(String dir2zip, ZipOutputStream zos){ 
        try{
          File zipDir = new File(dir2zip);
          String[] dirList = zipDir.list();

          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2156];
          int bytesIn = 0;

          for (String file : dirList) {

              File f = new File(zipDir, file);
              if (f.isDirectory()) {
                  String filePath = f.getPath();
                  zipDir(filePath, zos);
              }else{
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                ZipEntry anEntry = new ZipEntry(f.getPath());
                zos.putNextEntry(anEntry);

                while ((bytesIn = fis.read(readBuffer)) != -1) {
                    zos.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesIn);
                }

                fis.close();
            }

          }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }}

    public void startBackup(){
        try {
            File root = new File(".");

            File bfolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/backup/");

            if (!bfolder.exists())
                bfolder.mkdir();

            File backup = new File(bfolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/backup.zip");

            if (!backup.exists())
                backup.createNewFile();

            try{
                ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(backup));
                System.out.println(MessageManager.getConsolePrefix() + "Zipping files...");
                zipDir(root.getAbsolutePath(), zs);
                zs.close();
                System.out.println(MessageManager.getConsolePrefix() +"Done!");         
            }catch (Exception e){}

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
         java.util.Date dateTime = new java.util.Date();
         String date = dateFormat.format(dateTime);

         List<World> worlds = Bukkit.getWorlds();
         Object[] theWorlds = worlds.toArray();
         String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

         for(int i=0; i<theWorlds.length; i++){
             World w = (World) theWorlds[i];
             try {
                 w.save();
             } catch (Exception e1) {}

             String wNam = w.getName();
             File srcFolder = new File(path + File.separator + wNam);
             File destFolder = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "World Backups" + File.separator + date + File.separator + wNam);
             destFolder.mkdirs();
             if(srcFolder.exists()){
                 try{
                     Copier.copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
                 }catch(IOException e){}
             }
         }
    }
}
class Copier{
    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest) throws IOException{
        if(src.isDirectory()){
            if(!dest.exists())
                dest.mkdir();

            String files[] = src.list();
            for (String file : files) {
                File srcFile = new File(src, file);
                File destFile = new File(dest, file);

                copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }
        }else{
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Java 7 check out `try-with-resources`, it doesn't have anything to do with the answer, but you might find it helpful nonetheless.

Comment: A couple of things jump out.  First, you should be adding a "empty" zip entry for the directories (create zip entry, close zip entry).  Second, the paths should be relative to the root of the zip.  At the moment, you are adding the absolute paths ("C:\path\to\your\files") which will cause some issues if you want to unzip the archive later (as they will use the absolute path). Thirdly, you don't seem to be closing the zip entries when you done with them

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381281/creating-folders-in-a-zip-folder-in-java/16381391#16381391)

Comment: Hint:  See the [ZIP file specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) so you'll know what you're dealing with, and get yourself a hex editor/browser like [Hex Editor Neo](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor) so you can examine files you create.

Comment: ok, so I tried your suggestion about closing the entries, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/yed20EqH